# What exploit is the October 2017 Facebook messenger video using?

Tags: virus, facebook

There is currently a Facebook virus going around, where a user will receive a message from a friend directing them to a fake YouTube video. The when the user clicks through the virus is sent to their friends. [Here](http://www.news.com.au/technology/online/security/facebook-messenger-scam-tricks-you-into-clicking-on-virusriddled-youtube-channel/news-story/471830b9618e65b5113e8fdfc16a512f) is an article about this.

What is the mechanism that this virus is spreading? Is this a browser vulnerability? Or does involve the user downloading and giving explicit permission to execute malicious code?

Comment: From what the article is saying, it looks like a browser vulnerability that allows arbitrary code execution. But these news articles tend to be not too accurate when it comes to technical details. To answer your question thoroughly, more information is needed.

Comment: there can be a ton of vulns in older/unpatched browsers/OSes; the site iterates and looks for vulns, nothing specific for this video scam. The propagation is via malicious app, probably riding on top of existing facebook sessions.